# Styling a range slide without ::-webkit-slider-thumb

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to style a range input slider without using `::-webkit-slider-thumb` and `::-moz-range-thumb` since both of them are recommended by MDN to not be used on production sites.

### Non-standard

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
> use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
> user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
> implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: Your best bet is to create a custom slider.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing it's the only way around, now I understand why Google used custom slider instead of range input on YouTube. These form elements, they are just useless most of the times.

Comment: They're not useless, they're just not pretty enough

Comment: They were great if they were usable, if someone is okay with having 5 different looks in different browsers, then yeah... they should make styling of them easier.

Answer (score 0):

range inputs just style with ::-webkit-slider-thumb and ::-moz-range-thumb but thats work for some browser. Other browsers have their own styles. most sites use javascript to write a slider (and use css and range input isn't standard)